# How to call a method in another class using the arraylist index in java?

Tags: java

Currently I have two classes. A Classroom class and a School class.

`public void addTeacherToClassRoom(Classroom myClassRoom, String TeacherName)`

I would like my method addTeacherToClassRoom to use the Classroom Arraylist index number to setTeacherName

e.g. 
int 0 = maths
int 1 = science

I would like to setTeacherName "Daniel" in int 1 science.

many, thanks

```
    public class Classroom
{
private String classRoomName;
private String teacherName;

public void setClassRoomName(String newClassRoomName)
{
    classRoomName = newClassRoomName;

}

public String returnClassRoomName()
{
    return classRoomName;
}

public void setTeacherName(String newTeacherName)
{
    teacherName = newTeacherName;

}

public String returnTeacherName()
{
    return teacherName;
}
}





import java.util.ArrayList;

public class School
{
private ArrayList<Classroom> classrooms;
private String classRoomName;
private String teacherName;

public School()
{
    classrooms =  new ArrayList<Classroom>();
}

public void addClassRoom(Classroom newClassRoom, String theClassRoomName)
{
    classrooms.add(newClassRoom);
    classRoomName = theClassRoomName;
}

public void addTeacherToClassRoom(Classroom myClassRoom, String TeacherName)
{
    myClassRoom.setTeacherName(TeacherName);
}

}
```

Comment: It sounds like you want to assume that certain index values in your list will correspond to certain classes, however, with a dynamically expanding array, it seems like you would have a lot of trouble keeping track of which index was which. Perhaps you would be better off with a statically sized list such as Classroom[2]?

Answer (score 0):

```
public void addTeacherToClassRoom(Classroom myClassRoom, String TeacherName)
{
   myClassRoom.setTeacherName(TeacherName);
   classRooms.add(myClassRoom);
}
```

Is this enough?

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking to do something like this:

```
public void addTeacherToClassRoom(int classroomId, String TeacherName)
{
    if (classroomId < classrooms.size() ) {
        classrooms.get(classroomId).setTeacherName(TeacherName);
    }
}
```

This will access one of the Classroom objects in classrooms, and call the setTeacherName method on it.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the method you are looking for is classRooms.indexOf(myClassRoom). This should return the index of the classroom you are looking for.

However, for this to work reliably you should override and implement the hashCode() and equals() method on the Classroom class.

```
public void addTeacherToClassRoom(Classroom myClassRoom, String teacherName){
  int index = classrooms.indexOf(myClassRoom);
  if(index == -1){
    //The classroom isn't in the list yet.
    myClassRoom.setTeacherName(teacherName);
    classrooms.add(myClassRoom);
  }else{
    //Just update the teacher on the existing classroom.
    classrooms.get(index).setTeacherName(teacherName);
  }
}
```