# Returning the index number of an Arraylist in Java

Tags: java, indexing, arraylist

I would like my method `public void showClassRoomDetails(String teacherName)` to return the Arraylist index number using the teacherName.

Thanks

```
    import java.util.ArrayList;

public class School
{
private ArrayList<Classroom> classrooms;
private String classRoomName;
private String teacherName;

public School()
{
    classrooms =  new ArrayList<Classroom>();
}

public void addClassRoom(Classroom newClassRoom, String theClassRoomName)
{
    classrooms.add(newClassRoom);
    classRoomName = theClassRoomName;
}

public void addTeacherToClassRoom(int classroomId, String TeacherName)
{
    if (classroomId < classrooms.size() ) {
        classrooms.get(classroomId).setTeacherName(TeacherName);
    }
}

public void showClassRoomDetails(String teacherName)
{
    for (Classroom classroom : this.classrooms)
    {
        if (classroom.returnTeacherName().equals(teacherName))
        {
            System.out.println(classroom.returnClassRoomName());
            System.out.println(classroom.returnTeacherName());   
            break;
        }
    } 
}


}
```

Comment: Do you have a specific question?

Comment: Why did you downvote this? The "question" might be implicit, but clear enough, I guess?

Comment: a new user, but an extension of the following 'questions':  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4599283, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4596544, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4593232

Comment: while many of us are willing to help on homework problems, you should be showing what you have done to try and solve a problem, and asking for specific help.  We aren't here to write your homework one method at a time.

Comment: @RD You're right, I missed those ones...

Answer (score 4):

Use a regular loop, not the foreach loop:

```
public int showClassRoomDetails(String teacherName)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < this.classrooms.size(); i++)
    {
        Classroom classroom = classrooms.get(i);
        if (classroom.returnTeacherName().equals(teacherName))
        {
            return i;
        }
    } 

    // Return -1 when the teacher was not found
    return -1;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Either use a regular for loop (`for (int i=0;i<classrooms.size();i++)`) or use `ArrayList.indexOf(classroom)`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
for (int i = 0; i < classrooms.size(); i++) {
    Classroom classroom = classrooms.get(i);
    if (classroom.returnTeacherName().equals(teacherName)) {
        System.out.println("Index: " + i);
    }
}
```

Much more elegantly,

```
public int showClassRoomDetails(String teacherName) {
    for (int i = 0; i < classrooms.size(); i++) {
        Classroom classroom = classrooms.get(i);
        if (classroom.returnTeacherName().equals(teacherName)) {
            return i;
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

Alternatively, keep a counter that gets incremented for each `not true` condition (on your `if` statement).

Answer (score 0):

```
//Return set containing multiple matched indexes
public Set<Integer> showClassRoomDetails(String teacherName){
     Set<Integer> result = new HashSet<Integer>();
     int i=0;
     for (Classroom classroom : this.classrooms){
         if (classroom.returnTeacherName().equals(teacherName))
           result.add(i);
         i++;
     } 
   return result;
 }
```